# How does a group of transformations lead to a geometry?

Tags: lie-groups, euclidean-geometry

I am reading Vinberg's algebra text, and on page 144 he says "Of course, not every transformation group leads to a geometry which is interesting and also important for some applications. All such geometries are connected to quite rich transformation groups, and there are not many of them. The minimal condition here is transitivity."

He defines a group G to be a transitive group of some set X if for any two points in X there exists an element of G taking one to the other.  So in that sense, all points are congruent.

I am wondering about how transitive groups give rise to a "geometry".  For example, SO(3) would be a transitive group of the sphere, but not a transitive group of three-space.  Can someone explain this concept perhaps using SO(3) as an example and a non-example via those two sets, the sphere and three-space?

Comment: Might be of interest: [Erlangen program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program). If you can read French, I recommend the French version of this Wikipedia article.

Comment: The isometry group $Iso(\mathbb{R}^3)=O_3(\mathbb{R})\rtimes \mathbb{R}$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{R}^3$. With discrete cocompact subgroups $\Gamma\le Iso(\mathbb{R}^3)$ we have a rich geometry of crystallographic actions and flat compact Riemannian manifolds with fundamental group $\Gamma$.